# Why does sys.exit() not exit when called inside a thread in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.6

I am confused as to why the following code snippet would not exit when called in the thread, but would exit when called in the main thread.

```
import sys, time
from threading import Thread

def testexit():
    time.sleep(5)
    sys.exit()
    print "post thread exit"

t = Thread(target = testexit)
t.start()
t.join()
print "pre main exit, post thread exit"
sys.exit()
print "post main exit"
```

The docs for `sys.exit()` state that the call should exit from Python. I can see from the output of this program that "post thread exit" is never printed, but the main thread just keeps on going even after the thread calls exit.

Is a separate instance of the interpreter being created for each thread, and the call to `exit()` is just exiting that separate instance? If so, how does the threading implementation manage access to shared resources? What if I did want to exit the program from the thread (not that I actually want to, but just so I understand)?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

`sys.exit()` raises the `SystemExit` exception, as does `thread.exit()`. So, when `sys.exit()` raises that exception inside that thread, it has the same effect as calling `thread.exit()`, which is why only the thread exits.

Answer (score 49):

> What if I did want to exit the program from the thread?

#### For Linux:

```
os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT)
```

This sends a `SIGINT` to the main thread which raises a `KeyboardInterrupt`. While more complicated, this has the benefit that the main thread follows the standard shutdown with cleanup (e.g. threads, sockets, files, finally code). Also a handler can be setup, to react in a different.

#### For Windows:

The above does not work on Windows, as you can only send a `SIGTERM` signal, which is not handled by Python and has the same effect as `os._exit()`.

The only option is to use:

```
os._exit()
```

This will exit the entire process without any cleanup. If a cleanup is needed, the thread needs to communicate with the main thread in another way (e.g. through a queue or sending an event to its event-loop).

Comment: Also works with curses unlike [os._exit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5120178/483113)

Answer (score 27):

> What if I did want to exit the program
>   from the thread?

Apart from the method Deestan described you can call `os._exit` (notice the underscore). Before using it make sure that you understand that it does *no* cleanups (like calling `__del__` or similar).

Comment: Will it flush I/O ?

Comment: os._exit(n): "Exit the process with status n, without calling cleanup handlers, flushing stdio buffers, etc."

Comment: Note that when `os._exit` is used within curses the console isn't reset to a normal state with this. You have to execute `reset` in the Unix-shell to fix this.

Answer (score 14):

Is the fact that "pre main exit, post thread exit" is printed what's bothering you?

Unlike some other languages (like Java) where the analog to `sys.exit` (`System.exit`, in Java's case) causes the VM/process/interpreter to immediately stop, Python's `sys.exit` just throws an exception: a SystemExit exception in particular.

Here are the docs for `sys.exit` (just `print sys.exit.__doc__`):

> Exit the interpreter by raising SystemExit(status).
>   If the status is omitted or None, it defaults to zero (i.e., success).
>   If the status is numeric, it will be used as the system exit status.
>   If it is another kind of object, it will be printed and the system
>   exit status will be one (i.e., failure).

This has a few consequences:

- in a thread it just kills the current thread, not the entire process (assuming it gets all the way to the top of the stack...)
- object destructors (`__del__`) are potentially invoked as the stack frames that reference those objects are unwound
- finally blocks are executed as the stack unwinds
- you can catch a `SystemExit` exception

The last is possibly the most surprising, and is yet another reason why you should almost never have an unqualified `except` statement in your Python code.

Answer (score 14):

> What if I did want to exit the program
>   from the thread (not that I actually
>   want to, but just so I understand)?

My preferred method is Erlang-ish message passing.  Slightly simlified, I do it like this:

```
import sys, time
import threading
import Queue # thread-safe

class CleanExit:
  pass

ipq = Queue.Queue()

def testexit(ipq):
  time.sleep(5)
  ipq.put(CleanExit)
  return

threading.Thread(target=testexit, args=(ipq,)).start()
while True:
  print "Working..."
  time.sleep(1)
  try:
    if ipq.get_nowait() == CleanExit:
      sys.exit()
  except Queue.Empty:
    pass
```

Comment: You don't need a `Queue` here. Just a simple `bool` will do fine. The classic name for this variable is `is_active` and its initial default value is `True`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  According to http://effbot.org/zone/thread-synchronization.htm , modifying a `bool` (or any other atomic operation) will do perfectly for this particular problem.  The reason I go with `Queue`s is that when working with threaded agents I tend to end up needing several different signals (`flush`, `reconnect`, `exit`, etc...) almost immediately.

Comment: Deestan: Since a `bool` would work, as @Acumenus pointed out, then likewise a simple `int` would seem to be all that's needed to be able handle several different signals — `bool` is just a subclass of `int`, after all.

Answer (score 4):

`_thread.interrupt_main()` is available since Python 3.7 (optional before that)