# Python: How to quit CLI when stuck in blocking raw_input?

Tags: python, windows, blocking, command-line-interface, raw-input

I have a GUI program which should also be controllable via CLI (for monitoring). The CLI is implemented in a while loop using raw_input.
If I quit the program via a GUI close button, it hangs in raw_input and does not quit until it gets an input.

How can I immediately abort raw_input without entering an input?

I run it on WinXP but I want it to be platform independent, it should also work within Eclipse since it is a developer tool. Python version is 2.6.

I searched stackoverflow for hours and I know there are many answers to that topic, but is there really no platform independent solution to have a non-blocking CLI reader?

If not, what would be the best way to overcome this problem?

Thanks

Comment: "without pressing an additional key to get out of the raw_input?"  What does this mean?  Can you explain what you mean by this?  End-of-file is a key.  Control-C to kill the program is a key.  What is the "additional" key you're worried about?  Please be specific.

Comment: To quit the program I can either enter 'quit' in the CLI or close it via GUI.
If I quit the program via GUI, the CLI hangs in raw_input until I enter something in the CLI. How can I immediately abort raw_input without the need to enter an input?

Comment: @ S.Lott: I edited the question, please tell me if it is clear now.

Comment: "I can either enter 'quit' in the CLI or close it via GUI"?  That sounds like a toweringly bad design.  You should get rid of the CLI and implement whatever command-response business is going on as a proper part of the GUI.  A simple editable text widget is all you need.  But CLI + non-CLI user interface is a recipe for disaster.  Why are you doing it this way?

Comment: It was mainly out of historical reasons, the program and the GUI was already finished then a CLI was required, so I implemented it in the console thinking that this would be the simplest way. I'll think about that.

Comment: Another reason is that the program is only used company internal as a dev tool and it was more important to have maximum flexibility than useability.

Comment: Running into the same issue, I've posted my solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25419716/1224456)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not maybe the best solution but you could use the [thread module](http://docs.python.org/library/thread.html) which has a function `thread.interrupt_main()`. So can run two thread : one with your raw_input method and one which can give the interruption signal. The upper level thread raise a KeyboardInterrupt exception.

```
import thread
import time

def main():
    try:
        m = thread.start_new_thread(killable_input, tuple())
        while 1:
            time.sleep(0.1) 
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "exception" 

def killable_input():
    w = thread.start_new_thread(normal_input, tuple())
    i = thread.start_new_thread(wait_sometime, tuple())


def normal_input():
    s = raw_input("input:")


def wait_sometime():
    time.sleep(4) # or any other condition to kill the thread
    print "too slow, killing imput"
    thread.interrupt_main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: If I'm right, exceptions cannot be handled before raw_input is finished. So it is still an input needed and after that, the exception can be handled. I already tried to throw an exception from another thread.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't on windows because this code works on linux (if so then forget what I said).

Comment: You are right, using 'thread.interrupt_main()' it does also work on Windows. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what GUI toolkit you're using, find a way to hook up an event listener to the close window action and make it call [`win32api.TerminateProcess(-1, 0)`](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.5/pywin32/win32api__TerminateProcess_meth.html).

For reference, on Linux calling [`sys.exit()`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.exit) works.

Comment: I call sys.exit() but the problem is that exit waits for raw_input to end which does not happen before I press another key.

Comment: @christian Ah, you're on Windows (just read the question again). Will update answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, that will do it. But is there really no platform independent solution to have a non-blocking CLI reader?

Comment: @christian I'm not much of a Windows dev, so I can't say for sure. But if `sys.exit()` doesn't work for you, there is no other built-in Python function.