# How to stop Python PyGame program from a thread

Tags: python, pygame, python-multithreading

I have a thread in my PyGame test code, listening for the `pygame.QUIT` event. Whenever it detects that event it should quit the whole program. Instead, using `exit(0)` it only stops the listener thread.

```py
class ListenerThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        while True:
            print "Listening..."
            events = pygame.event.get()
            for event in events:
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    exit(0)

            time.sleep(1)

listener = ListenerThread()
listener.setDaemon(True)
listener.start()
```

The `print "Listening..."` and `time.sleep(1)` are there for test purposes only.

I also have some code there for graphics, and whenever I run the program, the terminal just says `Listening...` repeatedly, then when I click the 'x' button to close the window, the thread stops after the next `Listening...`, but the graphic stuff still keeps going on, so I have to close the program manually.

So, the question is, how do I close the whole program from within the thread?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489669/how-to-exit-the-entire-application-from-a-python-thread

Comment: @Rawing Ok, that worked, thanks. But I'm new here, so am I able to mark a comment as a working answer?

Comment: You can't. Just leave it and it'll be marked as a duplicate eventually.

Comment: @Rawing Oh yeah, of course :)

Comment: @Rawing See? I marked it myself. I are a smart people human!

Comment: I didn't even know that was possible, some intricacies of SO still elude me!