# how to make timer for quiting from python3

Tags: python, python-multithreading, python-3.6

I have a script and it doesn't work proper, so in bash I let script in while loop and I wanna my script can close itself after a while, I tried to use `threading.timer` but my code wont run `quit()` or `exit()` command, could anyone please help me?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import threading
from time import sleep

def qu():
  print("bye")
  exit()

t=threading.Timer(5.0,qu)
t.start()

while(True):
  sleep(1)
  print("hi")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `os._exit` function instead of `exit()`

Getting the code as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import threading
import os
from time import sleep

def qu():
    print("bye")
    os._exit(0)

t=threading.Timer(5.0,qu)
t.start()

while(True):
    sleep(1)
    print("hi")
```

Anyways I would suggest you to checkout [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489669/how-to-exit-the-entire-application-from-a-python-thread) as it is similar to yours.

Comment: tnx , for recalling my script i use `while [ True ];do python3 script.py;sleep 5;`done;`   is there any way I recall my script by pytion itself?

Comment: @SaebMolaee you're welcome, to call any script from python you can use the [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)