# Iterating through next after a certain amount of time

Tags: python, time, python-import

Let's say that I have the following code:

```
possibilities = range(20)
input_name = 4
for i in possibilities:
  exec("import Function_" + str(i))
  exec("Function_" + str(i) + ".solveproblem(" + str(input_name) + ")")
```

Since the second exec function, e.g. Function_3.solveproblem(4), can take infinity amount of time, I would just like to **try** (the function also can have some error) at most for 1,000 seconds and if the time exceeds, then I would like to stop that execution and go through the next function from another python file.

Any idea?

Comment: Try having a look here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-function-call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a timer with `time`

```
base = time.time() # Get time before start
for each in possibilities:
    ''do your stuff''
    if time.time()-base>100:
        break # Time limit
```

Or if it is impossible to slide it in, consider starting another thread

```
def timer:
    base = time.time() # Get time before start
    while True:
        if time.time()-base==100:
            thread.interrupt_main()

            break # Time limit
thread = threading.Thread(target=timer)

thread.start()

'''
now do the rest
'''
```

[How to exit the entire application from a Python thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489669/how-to-exit-the-entire-application-from-a-python-thread)