# Terminate Python program if input isn't specified in due timeframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, terminate

I'm trying to terminate python program if an input isn't provided by user within specific time frame, say - 5 seconds.

The code has been taken and edited from [mediocrity's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15530613/16462417)

```
import sys
import time
from threading import Thread

x = None

def check():
    global x
    time.sleep(5)
    if x:
        print("Input has been given!")
        return
    sys.exit()

Thread(target=check).start()
x = input("Input something: ")
```

But it keeps waiting for the input and doesn't terminate, unless the input is given.
How could I change the code so that it executes as inteded?

Comment: Did you read the comments below the answer that you copied? They say that it doesn't work.

Comment: I've tried that solution, it terminates process immediately without a delay. The output is ```You have 5 seconds to type in your stuff...
You typed None```

Comment: There are 23 answers at the linked question.

Comment: I'd also like to see if it could be done with threads and the code I supplied.

Comment: Actually, if you want to terminate the whole script, I think your original code should work. I'm not sure why it doesn't.

Comment: mediocrity's answer is the first one marked as a correct. Though that's irrelevant, the point is I borrowed the code from him and changed a little to suit my needs.

Comment: His code gives me the following output: `Input something: ` after five seconds its `Input something: Too Slow` and on the next line program still expects an input from user, it doesn't terminate

Comment: If you put `print("Too slow")` before `sys.exit()` in your code above, do you get that message? But it still doesn't exit the script?

Comment: Mine doesn't work either, that's what confused me as well.

Comment: It gives me the message, yes, but doesn't termiante.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489669/how-to-exit-the-entire-application-from-a-python-thread

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905189/why-does-sys-exit-not-exit-when-called-inside-a-thread-in-python

Comment: `os._exit(1)` worked from [Mark Rushakoff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1489838/16462417). Thanks tons!

Answer (score 0):

you should try this code its working on vscode

```
import sys
import time
from threading import Thread

x = None

def check():
  global x
  time.sleep(5)
  if x:
    print("Input has been given!")
    return
  else:
    print("input has not been given for last 5 sec") 
    sys.exit()
if __name__=='__main__':
  t1=Thread(target=check)
  t1.start()

  x = input("Input something: ")
  t1.join()
```