# How to terminate thread within two python files?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multiprocessing

#### script1.py

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def worker():
     while True:
     print(f"Working........")
     time.sleep(5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    demo = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=())
    demo.start()
    #demo.terminate()
```

#### script2.py

```
import time

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import script1
    print("script2......")
    time.sleep(2)
    script1.demo.terminate()
```

In `script2.py` file I'm unable to use `demo` showing

python3 script2.py

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "script2.py", line 9, in <module>
     script1.demo.terminate()
     AttributeError: module 'script1' has no attribute 'demo'`
```

Comment: Not sure if this is your answer but here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489669/how-to-exit-the-entire-application-from-a-python-thread

Comment: Your code is invalid due (mainly) to indentation issues. Also, you appear to be starting a Process and yet your title refers to Thread

Comment: remove `if __name__ == "__main__":` from `script1.py` because it skips code when you import file `script1.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you import `script1.py` then Python sets `__name__ = "script1"` and it doesn't run code in `if __name__ == "__main__":` - and it doesn't create `demo`. And you get error.

You can remove line `if __name__ == "__main__":` - and this is the simplest solution.

**script1.py**

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def worker():
    while True:
    print(f"Working........")
    time.sleep(5)

demo = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=())
demo.start()
#demo.terminate()
```

---

Or you can put code in function and execute function in `__main__` and later in `script2.py` - and this can be more useful because you may run this function many times in `script2.py`

**script1.py**

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def worker():
    while True:
    print(f"Working........")
    time.sleep(5)

def run_process():
    demo = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=())
    demo.start()
    return demo

if __name__ == "__main__":
    demo = run_process()
    #demo.terminate()
```

**script2.py**

```
import time

if __name__ == "__main__":

    import script1
    
    demo = script1.run_process()

    time.sleep(2)
    demo.terminate()
```

---

If you put `print()` in `__name__` in `script1.py` then you will see that `script1.py doesn't display it when you import code.

Comment: Thanks bro for you time, Now its working as expected.