# How to stop a python 2.7 program that has blocking calls in some threads

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, exit, sys

I have a Python program that has some threads that do blocking calls.
For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import threading, tty, sys, os, signal

# super-awesome thread launcher (re-inventing the wheel because I'm
# too lazy to research what they called this)
class Launch(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, f):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.f    = f
        self.start()
    def run(self):
        self.f()

# structure to hold unprocessed chars
Term_Lock    = threading.Lock()
Term_Cond    = threading.Condition(Term_Lock)
Term_In      = []

# launch a thread to retrieve characters from the terminal
tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
@Launch
def Stdin_Reader():
    while True:
        c = sys.stdin.read(1)
        with Term_Lock:
            Term_In.append(c)
            Term_Cond.notify()

# main thread
c = None
with Term_Lock:        
    Term_Cond.wait(1)
    if Term_In:
        c = Term_In.pop(0)
if c:
    print "You pressed '%s'\r" % c
else:
    print "You were too slow!\r"

# Lord have mercy on my soul
os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGKILL)
```

Although this program works just fine, that `os.kill()` at the end is a little bit unsettling. I have programmed in many other languages, and never seen this sort of issue before. I don't have a problem with the language inventor removing the _Exit call that should happen at the end of the main thread. But then to completely hide _Exit from the system APIs, now that's nerve.

Indeed, what we're seeing is basic questions about how to stop a program in a reasonable way. For example:

[Exit a process while threads are sleeping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602743/exit-a-process-while-threads-are-sleeping/1603009#1603009)

They say use Python 3.0 daemon threads. I'll keep that in mind for when Python 3.0 finally introduces general 2.7 compatibility. So the next best idea is to stop all the threads:

[Is there any way to kill a Thread in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python)

but the best-voted response is basically "don't do that". OK, fine. So take my example above. Blocking call to `sys.stdin.read()`. How do we fix that? They say use `select()`:

[Read file with timeout in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21429369/read-file-with-timeout-in-python)

Hold on though. Select only works with file descriptors and timeouts. What if I want to receive other inputs from programs and/or libraries that aren't using file descriptors to produce data? So I have to create in-memory pipes or something?? This is getting ridiculous fast.

So, do I just have to keep using `os.kill()` until Python 3.0 gains acceptance?

Or is there a better way?

Comment: If you do decide to go for file descriptors, pipes, select(), etc, you might be interested to look at ZeroMQ. If one is going down the Actor model, zmq can be a big help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that `os._exit(0)` is what I want:

[What is difference between sys.exit(0) and os._exit(0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591350/what-is-difference-between-sys-exit0-and-os-exit0)

It seems to work perfectly. I can even put it in my own `Exit()` function that can do whatever cleanups I want.