# How to close a thread from within?

Tags: python, multithreading

For every client connecting to my server I spawn a new thread, like this:

```
# Create a new client
c = Client(self.server.accept(), globQueue[globQueueIndex], globQueueIndex, serverQueue )

# Start it
c.start()

# And thread it
self.threads.append(c)
```

Now, I know I can close *all* the threads using this code:

```
    # Loop through all the threads and close (join) them
    for c in self.threads:
        c.join()
```

But how can I close the thread from *within* that thread?

Comment: `.join()` does not close a thread, everything it does is _waiting_ (by blocking the calling thread) for the joined thread to terminate itself.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

When you start a thread, it begins executing a function you give it (if you're extending `threading.Thread`, the function will be `run()`). To end the thread, just return from that function.

According to [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html), you can also call `thread.exit()`, which will throw an exception that will end the thread silently.

Comment: thread.exit() only works with the thread object, but not with threading.Thread class object.

Comment: Looks like exit() method is not available in python 3.7 After calling:
threading.enumerate()[1].exit()
I am getting an error:
AttributeError: 'Thread' object has no attribute 'exit'
Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 35):

How about `sys.exit()` from the module `sys`.

If `sys.exit()` is executed from within a thread it will close that thread only.

This answer here talks about that: [Why does sys.exit() not exit when called inside a thread in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905189/why-does-sys-exit-not-exit-when-called-inside-a-thread-in-python)

Comment: This is a great, simple solution.  Thank you!  Also, it can be used with the multiprocessing module or threading.

Comment: Although this works, just know it will also raise `SystemExit` which may not be an ideal solution depending on the use case.

Comment: easy and simple solution, works for me, thanks

Answer (score 30):

A little late, but I use a `_is_running` variable to tell the thread when I want to close. It's easy to use, just implement a stop() inside your thread class.

```
def stop(self):
  self._is_running = False
```

And in `run()` just loop on `while(self._is_running)`

Comment: What if I am not running in a loop?

Answer (score 6):

If you want force stop your thread:
`thread._Thread_stop()`
For me works very good.

Comment: To improve your answer, you should include _when_ it is a better alternative than the others listed here, along with a link to some documentation to support it.