# Stopping threads from inside a thread

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

In my code I have something like this:

```
import threading

def threaded():
    i = 0
    while True:
        if i == 2000:
            break
        i += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    thread = threading.Thread(target=threaded)
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()
    thread.join()
```

My question is, will the thread stop on its own when i is equal to 2000 or do I have to manually stop the thread using a custom implemented threading class?

Comment: yes the thread will stop when reaching 2000. But I hope this isn't your real code since that's a CPU-intensive loop (same thing for `while True: pass`: consider `thread.join()` to wait for thread termination.

Comment: He may use `thread.join()` to wait the child thread to finish, instead of using a infinite `while` loop.

Comment: this was just a example @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: I just added the `join()` method @LaurentLAPORTE

Comment: once `threaded` returns, the thread ends. Does that answer?

Comment: I think this question is a duplicate.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE difficult thing is: find the duplicate.

Comment: yes this answers thank you @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: found one here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4541190/1513933, not so hard indeed ;-)

Comment: Also see [_How to start and stop thread?_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15729498/how-to-start-and-stop-thread)