# Run python script after every X seconds taken as input from user

Tags: python, timer, scheduled-tasks, scheduling, apscheduler

I have the following python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json
import requests
import sys
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

#Function to get the health of the cluster
def getClusterHealth():
    try:
        response = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:2379/health')
        data = response.json()
        if data['health']=="true":
            print("Cluster is healthy")
            getClusterMetrics()
        elif data['health']!="true":
            print ("Cluster is not healthy")
            sendEmail()
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
        print e
        print("Cluster is down")
        sendEmail()

#Function to get the netrics of the cluster
def getClusterMetrics():
    try:
        response = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:2379/metrics')
        with open('clusterMetrics.txt','w') as f:
            f.write(response.text)
            f.close()
            print("Cluster Metrics saved in file: clusterMetrics.txt")
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
        print e
        sendEmail()

#Function to send emails in case of failures
def sendEmail():
    msg = MIMEText("etcd Cluster Down Sample Mail")
    sender = "etcd Cluster - 10.35.14.141"
    recipients = ["sample@email.com"]
    msg["Subject"] = "etcd Cluster Monitoring Test Multiple ID"
    msg['From'] = sender
    msg['To'] = ", ".join(recipients)
    s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
    s.sendmail(sender,recipients,msg.as_string())
    s.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    if(len(sys.argv) < 2):
        print("Usage : python etcdMonitoring.py [health|metrics]")
    elif(sys.argv[1] == "health"):
        getClusterHealth()
    elif(sys.argv[1] == "metrics"):
        getClusterMetrics()
```

I want to run the whole script X seconds as taken as input from user. However, using this input, I want to do some timer based functions in my functions. It should show the output/do certain things as I wish (cannot show the code here), but the inside functions will run for a multiple of input given by user. For example, if the input is 30, script should run every 30 seconds, but I should be able to check if the cluster is healthy every two minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a problem like this a while ago, just put the code that you want to execute every X seconds in a function then use threading python module to run it as a thread,, but don't forget to close the thread using `thread.cancel()` or `thread.exit()` before closing your program(using `atexit` or your own implementation) as the function will continue to execute if you don't.

```py
import atexit
import threading
X = input("Repeat code every ? sec")
def code(X):
  thread = threading.Timer(float(X), code)
  thread.start()
  '''
  your
  code
  '''
def exit():
  thread.cancel() #or thread.exit()
atexit.register(exit)
```

More Info:
[Run certain code every n seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393612/run-certain-code-every-n-seconds) 
[How to close a thread from within?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541190/how-to-close-a-thread-from-within)