# Programmatically exiting python script while multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading

I have some code which runs routinely, and every now and then (like once a month) the program seems to hang somewhere and I'm not sure where.

I thought I would implement [what has turned out to be not quite] a "quick fix" of checking how long the program has been running for. I decided to use multithreading to call the function, and then while it is running, check the time.

For example:

```
import datetime
import threading

def myfunc():
  #Code goes here

t=threading.Thread(target=myfunc)
t.start()
d1=datetime.datetime.utcnow()
while threading.active_count()>1:
  if (datetime.datetime.utcnow()-d1).total_seconds()>60:
    print 'Exiting!'
    raise SystemExit(0)
```

However, this does not close the other thread (myfunc).

What is the best way to go about killing the other thread?

Comment: Quite relevant:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/905189/132382

Comment: If you want other threads to die immediately when `SystemExit` is raised, make them daemon threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs could be clearer about this.  Raising `SystemExit` tells the interpreter to quit, but "normal" exit processing is still done.  Part of normal exit processing is `.join()`-ing all active non-daemon threads.  But your rogue thread never ends, so exit processing waits forever to join it.

As @roippi said, you can do

```
t.daemon = True
```

before starting it.  Normal exit processing does **not** wait for daemon threads.  Your OS should kill them then when the main process exits.

Another alternative:

```
import os
os._exit(13)  # whatever exit code you want goes there
```

That stops the interpreter "immediately", and skips **all** normal exit processing.

Pick your poison ;-)

Comment: Be aware that this breaks 'atexit' callbacks

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to kill a thread. You must kill the target from within the target. The best way is with a hook and a [queue](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html). It goes something like this.

```
import Threading
from Queue import Queue

# add a kill_hook arg to your function, kill_hook
# is a queue used to pass messages to the main thread
def myfunc(*args, **kwargs, kill_hook=None):
  #Code goes here
  # put this somewhere which is periodically checked.
  # an ideal place to check the hook is when logging
  try:
    if q.get_nowait():  # or use q.get(True, 5) to wait a longer
      print 'Exiting!'
      raise SystemExit(0)
    except Queue.empty:
      pass

q = Queue()  # the queue used to pass the kill call
t=threading.Thread(target=myfunc, args = q)
t.start()
d1=datetime.datetime.utcnow()
while threading.active_count()>1:        
  if (datetime.datetime.utcnow()-d1).total_seconds()>60:
  # if your kill criteria are met, put something in the queue
    q.put(1)
```

I originally found this answer somewhere online, possibly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/906401/1020470). Hope this helps!

Another solution would be to use a separate instance of Python, and monitor the other Python thread, killing it from the system level, with [psutils](https://code.google.com/p/psutil/).

Wow, I like the daemon and stealth os._exit solutions too!