# How do I exit an application from a thread in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, python-multithreading

Let's say I run a function in a thread that prints a number every 5 seconds, while the main application is running in the background:

```
import threading

def print_num(x):
    x += 1
    print(x)
    threading.Timer(5.0, print_num, [x]).start()

print_num(0)
main()
```

How do I close the main application and the thread itself if the number exceeds 100?

Comment: [`sys.exit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit)?

Comment: If I call `sys.exit()` from within the function it does only kill the thread not the main app.

Comment: @Rawing:  see the accepted answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905189/why-does-sys-exit-not-exit-when-called-inside-a-thread-in-python

Comment: `os._exit()`, but beware there is no cleanup and it cannot be trapped.