# kazoo DataWatch does not exit the program when exception is raised

Tags: python, apache-zookeeper, kazoo

I'm using kazoo=2.2.1, python 2.7, zookeeper 3.4.5--1.
I've set up a DataWatch, and if the callback raise an exception I'd like to abort the program. I'm unable to abort with the following code

```
from kazoo.recipe.watchers import DataWatch
from utils.zookeeper import Zookeeper
import time
import sys


def do_stuff(data, stat):
   raise NotImplementedError("abort")


def wrap_do_stuff(data, stat):
    try:
        do_stuff(data, stat)
    except Exception as e:
        if data != '':
            print e.message

            # This does not exit the program
            # sys.exit(-1)

            # This does not exit the program
            # raise e

            # This does not exit the program, just stop the watcher
            return False


def start():
    zookeeper_client = Zookeeper.init_from_config().client
    # Someone is writing into this node after creation
    new_node_path = zookeeper_client.create('/test/',
                                        ephemeral=True, sequence=True)
    path_to_watch = new_node_path
    print path_to_watch
    datawatcher = DataWatch(zookeeper_client, path_to_watch, wrap_do_stuff)

    while True:
        time.sleep(2)
        print "still alive"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start()
```

`

How do I abort in `wrap_do_stuff()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataWatch is run in a separate thread and there are specific ways to kill the main process from a thread, see [Why does sys.exit() not exit when called inside a thread in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905189/why-does-sys-exit-not-exit-when-called-inside-a-thread-in-python)

Something like `os._exit()` does work.