# How To Stop An Execution Python Script

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, exit

This is my code when I run this I want to exit the indicated time but I exit only `EndScript` I want a full script exit how I get an exit. please suggest to me thank you.

```
import threading
import datetime
import sys
from time import sleep


def EndScript():
    while True:
        print("============== EndScript Calling ==================", datetime.datetime.now().hour, datetime.datetime.now().minute)
        if datetime.datetime.now().hour >= 12 and datetime.datetime.now().minute >= 6:
            sys.exit()
        sleep(5)

def StartScript():
    thread1 = threading.Thread(target=EndScript)
    thread1.start()
    while True:
        print("===================== StartScript Calling ====================")
        sleep(2)
    

if(__name__ == '__main__'):
    StartScript()
```

Answer (score 0):

`sys.exit`() raises the `SystemExit` exception, as does `thread.exit()`. So, when `sys.exit()` raises that exception inside that thread, it has the same effect as calling `thread.exit()`, which is why only the thread exits. [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905189/why-does-sys-exit-not-exit-when-called-inside-a-thread-in-python)

In your use case, you can call `os._exit(0)` to exit the program on os level