# Stop execution of a script called with execfile

Tags: python, control-flow, execfile

Is it possible to break the execution of a Python script called with the execfile function without using an if/else statement? I've tried `exit()`, but it doesn't allow `main.py` to finish.

```
# main.py
print "Main starting"
execfile("script.py")
print "This should print"

# script.py
print "Script starting"
a = False

if a == False:
    # Sanity checks. Script should break here
    # <insert magic command>    

# I'd prefer not to put an "else" here and have to indent the rest of the code
print "this should not print"
# lots of lines below
```

Comment: Why are you using execfile() and not import?

Comment: I think execfile allows for more flexibility when I am editing the scripts in a separate window and executing them on the fly

Comment: Also Spyder uses `execfile()`, so this quesiton is relevant to anyone who wants to end their script but keep the console alive afterwards.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`main` can wrap the `execfile` into a `try`/`except` block: `sys.exit` raises a SystemExit exception which `main` can catch in the `except` clause in order to continue its execution normally, if desired. I.e., in `main.py`:

```
try:
  execfile('whatever.py')
except SystemExit:
  print "sys.exit was called but I'm proceeding anyway (so there!-)."
print "so I'll print this, etc, etc"
```

and `whatever.py` can use `sys.exit(0)` or whatever to terminate *its own* execution only. Any other exception will work as well as long as it's agreed between the source to be `execfile`d and the source doing the `execfile` call -- but `SystemExit` is particularly suitable as its meaning is pretty clear!

Comment: That seems like a hack to me.  Though Python is an exception-friendly language...

Comment: Exiting early from linear code requires one of return, continue, break, or raise (sys.exit() being a special case of raise).  raise is the *least* hackish in this context, IMO.

Comment: @Matthew, I agree with @Rick: in Python, exceptions aren't that exceptional (there's one, StopIteration, at the normal end of _every_ for loop, for example!), so using one to terminate the exec'd-file execution seems acceptable to me.

Comment: BTW, just to add more info: if you call `quit()`, it will also raise `SystemExit` and give the same message. Not if you call `os._exit()`.

Answer (score 4):

```
# script.py
def main():
    print "Script starting"
    a = False

    if a == False:
        # Sanity checks. Script should break here
        # <insert magic command>    
        return;
        # I'd prefer not to put an "else" here and have to indent the rest of the code
    print "this should not print"
    # lots of lines bellow

if __name__ ==  "__main__":
    main();
```

I find this aspect of Python (the `__name__` ==  `"__main__`", etc.) irritating.

Comment: There are two small errors in the code you posted: "print "this should not print"" is indented one too much and return does not need a semicolon. Thanks, I think I'll use this.

Comment: But then the lines are indented, which is what the OP wants to avoid. I don't understand why that indenting is to be avoided, though.

Comment: I fixed the print.  I'm keeping the semi-colon though. ;) Ah, how I hate significant whitespace.  :)

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with plain old exception handling?

scriptexit.py

```
class ScriptExit( Exception ): pass
```

main.py

```
from scriptexit import ScriptExit
print "Main Starting"
try:
    execfile( "script.py" )
except ScriptExit:
    pass
print "This should print"
```

script.py

```
from scriptexit import ScriptExit
print "Script starting"
a = False

if a == False:
    # Sanity checks. Script should break here
    raise ScriptExit( "A Good Reason" )

# I'd prefer not to put an "else" here and have to indent the rest of the code
print "this should not print"
# lots of lines below
```