# What is the best way to exit a function (which has no return value) in python before the function ends (e.g. a check fails)?

Tags: python, function, return

Let's assume an iteration in which we call a function without a return value. The way I think my program should behave is explained in this pseudocode:

```
for element in some_list:
    foo(element)

def foo(element):
    do something
    if check is true:
        do more (because check was succesful)
    else:
        return None
    do much much more...
```

If I implement this in python, it bothers me, that the function returns a `None`. Is there a better way for "exiting a function, that has no return value, if a check fails in the body of the function"?

Comment: Python always returns None if you don't explicitly return something. But you can leave the None off.

Comment: Depending on what the check is, you might also `raise` an exception (or, very rarely, make the function return True/False)

Answer (score 414, accepted):

You could simply use

```
return
```

which does exactly the same as

```
return None
```

Your function will also return `None` if execution reaches the end of the function body without hitting a `return` statement.  Returning nothing is the same as returning `None` in Python.

Comment: `return` doesn't work, if i set `a = method()` , inside method i use `return`, it still keep running code behind a. exit should be like php exit(), it breaks the program instantly.

Comment: @TomSawyer to stop a Python program early, do `import sys` first and then [`sys.exit()`](https://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.exit) if you want to exit but report success or `sys.exit("some error message to print to stderr")`.

Comment: @Boris, this is what I was looking for and this worked for me.

Comment: @TomSawyer what you ask for is the topic of a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73663/how-to-terminate-a-python-script)! Ordinary `return` works perfectly well for what _this_ OP described.

Answer (score 21):

I would suggest:

```
def foo(element):
    do something
    if not check: return
    do more (because check was succesful)
    do much much more...
```

Answer (score 18):

you can use the `return` statement without any parameter to exit a function

```
def foo(element):
    do something
    if check is true:
        do more (because check was succesful)
    else:
        return
    do much much more...
```

or raise an exception if you want to be informed of the problem

```
def foo(element):
    do something
    if check is true:
        do more (because check was succesful)
    else:
        raise Exception("cause of the problem")
    do much much more...
```

Answer (score 12):

1. `return None` or `return` can be used to exit out of a function or program, both does the same thing
2. `quit()` function can be used, although use of this function is discouraged for making real world applications and should be used only in interpreter.

```py
    import site
    
    def func():
        print("Hi")
        quit()
        print("Bye")
```

3. `exit()` function can be used, similar to `quit()` but the use is discouraged for making real world applications.

```py
import site
    
    def func():
        print("Hi")
        exit()
        print("Bye")
```

4. `sys.exit([arg])` function can be used and need to `import sys` module for that, this function can be used for real world applications unlike the other two functions.

```py
import sys 
  height = 150
  
if height < 165: # in cm 
      
    # exits the program 
    sys.exit("Height less than 165")     
else: 
    print("You ride the rollercoaster.")
```

5. `os._exit(n)` function can be used to exit from a process, and need to `import os` module for that.