# How can I end the script early if certain condition is met (Using input as string)

Tags: python, string, if-statement, exit

This is my beginner homework for creating urinalysis specimen quality evaluation for urine culture. I want to end the script early if a certain condition is met, but the script is still continuing. How can I end the script early?

```
print("Welcome to urinalysis specimen quality evaluation for urine culture")
no_epithelial_cell = input("Question 1 : Do epithelial cells in your specimen few or numerous? ")
if no_epithelial_cell == "Numerous" or "numerous" :
    print("Specimen not qualified. Reject specimen ")
if no_epithelial_cell == "Few" or "few" :
    no_bacteria = (input("Question 2 : Do bacterias in your specimen few or numerous? "))
        if no_bacteria == "Numerous" or "numerous" :
            print("Specimen not qualified. Reject specimen ")
        if no_bacteria == "Few" or "few" :
            no_WBC = (input("Question 2 : Does WBC in your specimen positive or negative? "))
                if no_WBC == "Positive" or "positive" :
                    print("Suspect UTI. Proceed urine culture ")
                if no_WBC == "Negative" or "negative" :
                    print("No evidence of UTI ")
```

Comment: Your understanding of the syntax required when using `or` is wrong

Comment: Please add the language tag.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/6190798/4322960

Answer (score 0):

A few things first off, the `or` keyword is not what you think it does. It works like this: `(expr1) or (expr2)`, expr1 and expr2 being full expressions. That means, your first `if no_epithelial_cell == "Numerous" or "numerous":` wouldn't work, because it would have to be written like this: `if no_epithelial_cell == "Numerous" or no_epithelial_cell == "numerous":`, which can be condensed into `if no_epithelial_cell.lower() == "numerous":`, which will account for all other spellings of the word aswell.

To end a script early, just call `exit(0)`, 0 being the exit code. 0 in this case means that the script has executed successfully. If you want to return from a function instead, use `return`