# How to exit in Python 3.2?

Tags: function, python-3.x

I know now we cant use **sys.exit()** . So how do I exit in the new version of Python?

Comment: What makes you say you can't use `sys.exit()`? It appears in the documentation for Python 3.2.2: http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/sys.html#sys.exit

Comment: This question is in no way ambiguous, is a real question, and can totally be reasonably answered in its current form...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
import sys
sys.exit()
```

details from the [sys module documentation](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-sys.html):

> exit([arg])
>
> Exit from Python. This is 
>   implemented by raising the SystemExit
>   exception, so cleanup actions
>   specified by finally clauses of try
>   statements are honored, and it is
>   possible to intercept the exit attempt
>   at an outer level. The optional
>   argument arg can be an integer giving
>   the exit status (defaulting to zero),
>   or another type of object. If it is an
>   integer, zero is considered
>   `successful termination'' and any
>   nonzero value is considered`abnormal
>   termination'' by shells and the like.
>   Most systems require it to be in the
>   range 0-127, and produce undefined
>   results otherwise. Some systems have a
>   convention for assigning specific
>   meanings to specific exit codes, but
>   these are generally underdeveloped;
>   Unix programs generally use 2 for
>   command line syntax errors and 1 for
>   all other kind of errors. If another
>   type of object is passed, None is
>   equivalent to passing zero, and any
>   other object is printed to sys.stderr
>   and results in an exit code of 1. In
>   particular, sys.exit("some error
>   message") is a quick way to exit a
>   program when an error occurs.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73663/terminating-a-python-script)

Comment: So this is normal?                                           Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\test", line 5, in <module>
    sys.exit()
SystemExit

Comment: @KarthikSampath: If you get an error, it's a good idea to say so in the question. Please update the question with code example and full excption.   sys.exit() does raise a SystemExit exception, yes. Your code probably catches that exception somewhere.

Comment: Ok Thanks. I thought would just exit the program like in C++. Sorry for the trouble.