# Using app.exec() instead of sys.exit(app.exec_()) with PyQT4 in Spyder will not work

Tags: pyqt4, spyder

I am developing a PyQT program using the Spyder IDE (which uses IPython) on a Windows 7 machine, and I am having trouble with the statement `sys.exit(app.exec_())`. I have read this post

[What the error when I close the dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25007104/what-the-error-when-i-close-the-dialog/25007161#25007161)

and tried using just `app.exec_()`. When I use just `app.exec_()`, however, the GUI very briefly opens and then closes immediately. Here is my minimum (not) working example:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Button', self)   
        self.show()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    app.exec_()
    #sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is my first post on stackoverflow, so if I could improve this post in any way, please let me know.

Comment: Upon further investigation, it appears that this is an issue specifically with Spyder, and not IPython in general. I ran the code above in a Jupyter notebook, and it produced the GUI without any problem. So any insight into why this does not work in Spyder would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution. Apparently you do not need to include `app.exec_()` at all, according to

http://cyrille.rossant.net/making-pyqt4-pyside-and-ipython-work-together/

The following code works in Spyder:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Button', self)   
        self.show()

ex= Example()
```