# Unable to see app windows created by PySide2 in Spyder

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder, pyside2

I'm trying to run an app with `PySide2` from `Spyder 3.2.8` and `Python 3.6.4` in Anaconda in a `macOS 10.13.4`.

**attempt N°1**

After having seen this [stackoveflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49094112/when-running-pyqt5-app-in-spyder-it-always-exits-with-1) and this [github page](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/How-to-run-PyQt-applications-within-Spyder) I changed my graphic backend from `Inline` to `Automatic` in `Python > Preferences > IPython Console > Graphics` and I tried to run the following script (*script N°1*):

*script N°1*

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *

# Create a Qt application
app = QApplication.instance()
if app is None: 
    print("print something")
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
# Create a Label and show it
label = QLabel("Hello World")
label.show()
# Enter Qt application main loop
app.exec_()
```

but got the following error message after running it:

```
Importing PySide2 disabled by IPython, which has
already imported an Incompatible QT Binding: pyqt5
```

There are similar reported issues [here with matplotlib](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/10543/) and [here with ipython](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/5643) but it didn't help me (or I couldn't implement it properly). Then I tried to implement the content of [this page about qtpy](https://github.com/git-cola/git-cola/blob/master/qtpy/__init__.py) by changing the *script N°1* in the following way:

*script N°2*

```
import os
os.environ['QT_API'] = 'pyside2'
from qtpy.QtWidgets import *
import sys

# Create a Qt application
app = QApplication.instance()
if app is None: 
    print("print something")
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
# Create a Label and show it
label = QLabel("Hello World")
label.show()
# Enter Qt application main loop
app.exec_()
```

**attempt N°2**

With `Inline` selected in `Python > Preferences > IPython Console > Graphics`. When I ran the *script N°2* , the app launches and I got `print something` printed in to the console. When closing the app, I got `Out[1]: 0` in the console. However when I run the script again, no error message appears in the console but the window of the app doesn't show-up

**attempt N°3**

This time with `Automatic` selected in `Python > Preferences > IPython Console > Graphics`. When I ran the *script N°2* the first time, the app didn't launch and I got the following error message

```
/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/qtpy/__init__.py:178: RuntimeWarning: Selected binding "pyside2" could not be found, using "pyqt5"
'using "{}"'.format(initial_api, API), RuntimeWarning)
Out[2]: -1
```

**attempt N°4**

With `Automatic` selected in `Python > Preferences > IPython Console > Graphics`. When I ran the *script N°1* after having changed the line from `PySide2.QtWidgets import *` to `from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *`: The app didn't launch and I got the following error message

```
Out[1]: -1
```

**attempt N°5**

With `Inline` selected in `Python > Preferences > IPython Console > Graphics`. When I ran the *script N°1* after having changed the line from `PySide2.QtWidgets import *` to `from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *`: The app launches and I got `print something` printed in to the console. I closed the app and got `Out[1]: 0` in the console. However when I run the script again, no error message appears in the console but the window of the app doesn't show-up

N.B. this question is the continuation of [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50228304/needs-to-delete-kill-a-python-page-after-running-a-gui-pyside2-or-pyqt)

Comment: Does everything work properly with pyqt5?

Comment: thank you @ekhumoro. No it didn't work with pyqt5. I edited the question and wrote the attempts and output while using pyqt5

Comment: I found kind a solution to the problem by running the _script N°1_ in `Atom` with packages `scripts` and `hydrogen`. This solution not perfect because the `app window` appears in the back (behind the `Atom-python-IDE window`) ==> you have to move/minimize the `Atom-python-IDE window` each time you open it to have access to the `app window`. However with this solution you don't have to kill/delete manually the app after you hit the quit button

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Since the `ipykernel` package (which is used by Spyder to run code in its consoles) doesn't have event loop support for PySide2 as of May/2018 (as can be seen [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/blob/4.8.2/ipykernel/eventloops.py)), you won't be able to run PySide2 code inside Spyder, **no matter what you try**.

*Notes*:

1. The `Automatic` backend tries to select a suitable event loop for you, in this order: Qt5, Qt4, Tk and Inline. That's why it doesn't work in your case.
2. Every time you change a Graphics backend in Spyder, you need to restart the kernel of the console you want to run your code in. That's because you can only use one backend per console session (this is a limitation imposed by `ipykernel`, not by us). It's clear from your question that you're not doing that.
3. We're aware we fail to inform users when a kernel restart is necessary. We'll try to address that in our next major version (Spyder 4), to be released in 2019.
4. If you already know about `qtpy`, please use it to develop your apps instead of using PySide2 directly. That way you could work with PyQt5 for development in Spyder, but PySide2 for deployment, since `qtpy` takes care of working seamlessly with whatever binding is available.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Could you please comment on the situation with PyQt5 (see attempt N°5 in the question)? Because it seems that that doesn't work properly for the OP either.