# Tensorflow error running retrain.py in colab.research.google.com

Tags: google-colaboratory

Any help on what this means. I got code from tensorflow for poets and it seemed to train but right near the end it fails with a non descriptive error running 
retrain.py.  I am running this in cloud on the google colaboratory.

Final test accuracy = 90.7% (N=353)
INFO:tensorflow:Froze 2 variables.
Converted 2 variables to const ops.
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:2890: UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
  warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)

Answer (score 0):

Final test accuracy = 90.7% (N=353) INFO:tensorflow:Froze 2 variables. Converted 2 variables to const ops. 
This means that the model has been tested, and successfully saved to a frozen graph, ready to be served.

UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D. warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)
Is not an error, it's a warning, so no big deal. It's not even tensorflow related. What really caused that warning to happen is beyond me, maybe this can help:
https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/4639
[What the error when I close the dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25007104/what-the-error-when-i-close-the-dialog)

Comment: My posting is missing my edit where I dump what the error was by typing %tb but if you are telling me the .pb file was created successfully I am Ok with that.