# How to Terminate the Script in Python

Tags: python

I want to know about how do I stop my python script after completing a process I'm running a .py script I want it to stop automatically after completing the 10th page. like
I want to start it

```
pageIndex += 1
```

and want to stop it after completing it.

```
pageIndex >= 10
```

Comment: you can stop the script by calling sys.exit(0)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73663/terminating-a-python-script

Answer (score 1):

If you `import` the `sys` module, you can use the `sys.exit()` command at the point you wish to terminate your script. Something along the lines of:

```
if pageIndex >= 10:
    sys.exit()
```

It's worth noting that `sys.exit()` will terminate ALL running python scripts.