# Python 3.6 quit() not working after porting to exe

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I have a small tkinter gui that generates some reports. I built a quit button into it. The button works perfectly when I launch the script, but I converted it to an exe with cx_freeze and the entire program is working except the quit button.

```
def quits():
    quit()
```

I created the quit button to call this `quits` function because I read that just calling quit directly could cause problems. Anyone have any idea why this is not working as an exe?

Comment: You should `import sys; sys.exit(0)` instead.

Comment: quit() is an interpreter function, not a Python language function.  It exits the interpreter.  Since you're running a C program, there is no interpreter to exit.  Are you getting an error or is the button just not doing anything?  In any case, I found this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73663/terminating-a-python-script.  Use sys.exit() or os._exit() instead to kill a thread or an entire program at the C level

Comment: Please read the documentation of [`quit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#quit): "[...] useful for the interactive interpreter shell and should not be used in programs".

Comment: I believe [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19747562/7073884) will provide more than enough information.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys I will look into the sys functions. I am not getting any errors. Still pretty new to this so no errors makes it hard to troubleshoot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments the `quit` function doesn't work outside of the interpreter

```
def quits():
    sys.exit()
```

That does the trick