# Python break/return a recursive function for sum of subsets

Tags: python

I am trying to implement [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632322/finding-all-possible-combinations-of-numbers-to-reach-a-given-sum?noredirect=1&lq=1) to find if the sums of any subsets equal a target value:

```
def subset_sum(numbers, target, partial=[]):
    s = sum(partial)

    # check if the partial sum is equals to target
    if s == target: 
        print "sum(%s)=%s" % (partial, target)
    if s >= target:
        return  # if we reach the number why bother to continue

    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        n = numbers[i]
        remaining = numbers[i+1:]
        subset_sum(remaining, target, partial + [n])
```

However, I would like the function to 'break' / return once there is an instance of the target being met, so that it doesn't continue to find more.

I've tried this, but it still continues:

```
def subset_sum(numbers, target, partial=[]):
    s = sum(partial)

    # check if the partial sum is equals to target
    if s == target: 
        print "sum(%s)=%s" % (partial, target)
        return   // should stop once reaches one instance
    if s >= target:
        return  # if we reach the number why bother to continue

    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        n = numbers[i]
        remaining = numbers[i+1:]
        subset_sum(remaining, target, partial + [n])
```

Comment: Mechanical: `partial=[]` means that `partial` is bound to a list instance created during the `def`. If you ever modify that list instance, bad things happen. You don't so that's OK, but I'd split this into the recursive code that has a `partial` and the outer call that doesn't, both for readability and for safety. Then use Reputation Farmer's method: have the recursive call tell you if it succeeded.

Comment: what is "numbers"? can you add, how you run the function with arguments.

Comment: Note also that your "s >= target" test assumes that no values in `numbers` are negative, but there's no documentation or test asserting that this is the case.

Comment: Note that return always returns to the previous call and in your recursive function call it returns to previous function call. If you want to exit the program itself you could try something similar to sys.exit
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73663/terminating-a-python-script for options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited: Missed the original algorithm, this should return the first valid list.

Try this:

```
def subset_sum(numbers, target, partial=[]): 
    s = sum(partial) # check if the partial sum is equals to target 
    if s >= target: # if we reach the number why bother to continue 
        return partial
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        n = numbers[i]
        remaining = numbers[i+1:]
        results = subset_sum(remaining, target, partial + [n])
        if results:
            return results
```

Comment: But this isn't the algorithm and wouldn't yield required result/s

Comment: You're right, I missed that.  Updated so it returns the first list valid.

Answer (score 0):

Make `subset_sum` return bool: whether the subset was found. Check results of recursive calls.

```
def subset_sum(numbers, target, partial=[]):
    s = sum(partial)

    # check if the partial sum is equals to target
    if s == target: 
        print "sum(%s)=%s" % (partial, target)
        return True   # should stop once reaches one instance
    if s > target:
        return False # if we reach the number why bother to continue

    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        n = numbers[i]
        remaining = numbers[i+1:]
        if subset_sum(remaining, target, partial + [n]):
            return True
    return False
```

A better approach may be to return the answer (i.e. `partial`) or `None`.