# How should I exit this python program?

Tags: python

```
quit2 = True
while quit2 == True:
    delete = input('\nIf you would like to delete a guest, enter their guest number. '
                   '\nIf you would  like to skip this step press Enter.')

if isinstance(delete, int):
    list[delete].remove()
else:
    break
```

## I can't use quit2 = '' and While not quit2 by the way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Terminating a Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73663/terminating-a-python-script)

Comment: if you dont set new value to quit2 will never change... (list[delete].remove()) doesnt make sense for me

Comment: What's the point of `quit2` if you aren't allowed to modify it? Just use `while True:` if you have an explicit `break` condition in the loop.

Comment: `delete` will never be an instance of `int`; `input` always returns a `str`. You probably want `delete = int(delete)`, with a `try` statement to catch any errors in the conversion attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `if` statement not being in the `while` loop is a formatting issue in the question, then the only problem with this code is that the `if` statement condition will never be true, since `input()` always returns a `string`, not an `int`.

Instead of using an `if/else` block, maybe try a `try/except` block:

```
while True:  # Don't need 'quit2', since it's never going to change
    delete = input('\nIf you would like to delete a guest, enter their guest number. '
                   '\nIf you would  like to skip this step press Enter.')

    try:
        delete = int(delete)
        list[delete].remove()
    except ValueError:  # if int(delete) fails because the string isn't numeric, exit loop
        break
    except IndexError:  # if list index out of range, let them try again
        print("That guest doesn't exist. Please try again.")
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

use **break** inside your while loop inside an **if** so the rest of your code will continue, but if you want to terminate it: import sys and use sys.exit()