# Is there a way to terminate my program after a condition is met? (If a player won the game)

Tags: python, terminate

I just learned Python about a week ago (I don't have any programming experience), but I tried to recreate the snakes and ladders game. I coded it but I don't know how to terminate the program if a player won. After a player has won (reached 100 or any board size), my program still asks another player to roll the dice and the game just continues.

Here is the Player class I created.
You can find the win condition in `Player.turn()`.

```py
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = str(name)
        self.position = int()

    def ask_to_roll(self):
        while True:
            command = str(input("Press enter to roll the dice.\n> "))
            if command == "":
                break
            else:
                print("Invalid")
                continue

    def roll_dice(self):
        print(f'{self.name} is rolling the dice...')
        time.sleep(delay)
        roll_result = random.randint(1, dice_faces)
        print(f"It's a {roll_result}!")
        time.sleep(delay)
        return roll_result

    def check_for_snakes_ladders(self):
        if self.position in snakes.keys():
            print(random.choice(snake_bite))
            time.sleep(delay)
            print(f'{self.name} fell from {self.position} to {snakes[self.position]}')
            time.sleep(delay)
            self.position = snakes[self.position]
        elif self.position in ladders.keys():
            print(random.choice(ladder_jump))
            time.sleep(delay)
            print(f'{self.name} climbed from {self.position} to {ladders[self.position]}')
            time.sleep(delay)
            self.position = ladders[self.position]
        else:
            pass

    def turn(self):
        print(f"\nIt's {self.name}'s turn")
        self.ask_to_roll()
        roll_result = self.roll_dice()
        new_position = self.position + roll_result
        if new_position > board_size:
            print(f"Oops you need to get {board_size - self.position}")
            pass
        elif new_position == board_size:
            print(f'{self.name} won')*
        elif new_position < board_size:
            print(f'{self.name} moved from {self.position} to {new_position}')
            time.sleep(delay)
            self.position = new_position
            self.check_for_snakes_ladders()
```

Comment: You can use `sys.exit()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to terminate a Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73663/how-to-terminate-a-python-script)

Comment: Can I put that after the print(f'{self.name} won')?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
elif new_position == board_size:
    print(f'{self.name} won')
    sys.exit(0)
```

Remember to `import sys` at the top of the file