# Stopping a program in if statement

Tags: python, validation, if-statement, exit

I can't stop my program in an if statement where I want to check if the number given by the user is a positive one (>0). I get my message if I give a negative number, but the program goes on and shows more messages.

Any idea how to stop it there?

Here is the part I'm trying to fix:

```
#number validation
if user_age<0 :
    print("Not a valid number")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to terminate a Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73663/how-to-terminate-a-python-script)

Comment: The linked duplicate is a brute-force hammer that solves the problem as asked; but you should instead try to write your code in a way that there just isn't anything else that happens afterward. Some useful tools for this are `return`ing from a function that contains the main work of the script, and using the matching `else` for your `if`.