# how to stop at a line outside a function

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I believe my question has been asked before but i don't know how to explain what i want to do

I basically have this code that i want to stop the execution at a spisific line

```
  #embed
  embed_var = discord.Embed(
    title= ''' title ''', 
    description= ''' description ''', 
    color= discord.Color.red())
  embed_var.set_footer(text=''' footer ''')
  embed_var.add_field(name=''' name ''', value=''' value ''', inline=True)

  #stop here

  print(''' don't print this ''')
```

Edit: sorry i guess i didn't phrase it currectly, i want the program to keep going but to not to keep executing the rest of the cod

Comment: Simply use `raise SystemExit` or `sys.exit()`.

Comment: sorry i guess i didn't phrase it currectly, i want the program to keep going but to not to keep executing the rest of the code

Comment: just comment it out then?

Comment: Put that code in a function and use ```return``` where you want to stop. Post your code completely for us to help.

Comment: Then comment out the code you don't want to run as suggested by @Guddi or add an `if` statement. E.g. `run = False` then `if run: # code not to run`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is in a loop, `break` and `continue` might be what you are looking for: [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_loop_control.htm)

If this is a function, you can use `return`: [link](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-return-stmt)

If you wish your program to exit entirely, use `sys.exit()`: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73663/how-to-terminate-a-script)

If this is for debug purposes, you can always comment out the code using a `#` sign: [link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_comments.asp)

Comment: thanks for the multiple solutions, i wanted to do this for debugging reasons of which i found using "function" to be the easiest in practice. there is another good solution @Guddi mentioned which is to just comment the rest of the code

Comment: For debugging purposes, I would recommend using a debugger like [pdb](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html).

Comment: I've added comments to the answer, good call

Answer (score -2):

There are several ways to interrupt Python execution process.

You may check it here [Python exit commands - why so many and when should each be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19747371/python-exit-commands-why-so-many-and-when-should-each-be-used)

For your case,

```
import sys 

  #embed
  embed_var = discord.Embed(
    title= ''' title ''', 
    description= ''' description ''', 
    color= discord.Color.red())
  embed_var.set_footer(text=''' footer ''')
  embed_var.add_field(name=''' name ''', value=''' value ''', inline=True)
  
  sys.exit() # to exit from execution process
  #stop here

  print(''' don't print this ''')
```

It is better to have a condition why the program should skip some script, you can use `if` or if you are in a loop, you can use `continue`

Comment: *OP:* `i want the program to keep going but to not to keep executing the rest of the code`