# How can I make the code carry out a function if a variable a is equal to a string or integer?

Tags: string, input, python-3.7, equality

I'm doing a simple program for practice, and I've stumbled upon a problem. I want the program to terminate if I don't get a string input, but it isn't working.

```
            if num_2 != int
                break
```

But nothing I try works, what should I do?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14836329/15368978) answer your question?